# NFC Writting Error - Only one tag technology can be connected at a time

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

i have an issue with witting to NFC chips. The writing works fine on a few chips. My client rely heavily on writing the tags at high numbers lets say 30 tags. When they write to the tags there is a warning message only one tag technology can be connected at a time – there is only writing to one tag, there are no other tag near. This happens after about the 4th tag is written too.

Any assistance is much appreciated

Ionic:
Ionic CLI: 6.20.1
Ionic Framework: @ionic/angular 6.2.2
angular-devkit/build-angular: 13.0.4
angular-devkit/schematics: 13.0.4
angular/cli: 13.0.4
ionic/angular-toolkit: 5.0.3

Cordova:
Cordova CLI: 11.0.0
Cordova Platforms: android 10.1.2
Cordova Plugins:
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0,
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0,

Utility:
cordova-res: 0.15.4
native-run (update available: 1.7.2) : 1.5.0

System:
Android SDK Tools: 26.1.1
NodeJS: v14.20.0
npm: 6.14.17
OS: Windows 10